# Authenticate users in Postgres using kerberos without a password

Tags: postgresql, authentication, active-directory, kerberos

I'm trying to get authentication working using kerberos in Windows instead of username and password when connecting to PostgreSQL. Very new to this area and would appreciate any thoughts. In essence what I want to achieve is not having the password in the app configuration. Maybe there are other options apart from using kerberos?

Will the following work?

- configure Postgres for SSPI authentication
- create a user in Postgres with the same user name as the SPN of the user in the AD
- pre-create kerberos authentication tickets (somehow magically) for the created user
- connect to postgres using psql with the above user without providing the password

If this is at all possible I'm interested in how to achieve that magical part above ^^^

Thanks.